# Is there another name for finite step controller?

Tags: controller, control-theory

My control theory professor is not a native English speaker. He gave me the homework to tune in a sampled controller with the finite step controller method. The only problem is that I think he this method has a different name in English and it is only a word-by-word translation. Do you guys have any guesses what might b the more poplar name of the method?

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe the method at all?

If you are in an introductory course, he is probably referring to tuning a controller to provide a desired "step response" by placing system poles or loop shaping.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_response

Comment: yes, we have calculated the transfer function of the plant and need to tune a discrete controller

Comment: In that case I would assume he is simply referring to implement a simple PD or PID controller.

Answer (score 0):

He probably means a deadbeat controller - it achieves zero steady state error after finite amount of control steps.